# update a column of the first 5000 rows of a table in MYSQL version 5.1.11

Tags: mysql, limit, sql-update

I have a situation in which I need to update some values of a column in a table in batches(i.e. first 5000 rows).

So I wrote a query as

```
update clientdetails set lastupdateddate=now where id in (Select id from clientdetails limit 1,5000);
```

The error is prompted as this version of MYSQL doesn't support Limit 1,5000.
So is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: your query doesn't make much sense regarding your WHERE clause. It would make sense, if the table your sub-querying was a different one than the one you're updating. (Which should not work at all, seeing that MySQL can't read/write the same table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just do it this way:

```
update clientdetails set lastupdateddate=now where <your where clause> 
limit <desired limit>;
```

?

Comment: Edited, just add it to the query.

Comment: Firstly I tried with that only but the error was same. Isn't there any other logic?

Comment: Hmm, dunno why, then, it should work. But maybe try rodneyrehm's JOIN suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a couple of problems with [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) and sub-queries.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE foo IN (SELECT foo FROM table2 LIMIT 50)
```

is not possible. But the following is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t
JOIN (SELECT foo FROM table2 LIMIT 50) as tmp
ON tmp.foo = t.foo;
```

I beliebe this "(query) as table" thing is called a "virtual temporary view" (but I may be wrong here...)

The second Problem you're facing is that you can't udate a table you're currently reading from.

But (as Griwes pointed out) the UPDATE knows a LIMIT:

```
UPDATE clientdetails 
SET lastupdateddate = NOW() 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 0, 5000;
```

should work. Make sure you've got the ORDER BY in there, otheriwse you might be UPDATING some rows twice and some never.

Comment: +1 for mentioning order by. Not sure if you'd have double updates, but there isn't a guarantee of which 5000 are updated otherwise.